# Playwright execution context destroyed after call to page.evaluate()

Tags: web-scraping, playwright, browser-automation, playwright-python

First and foremost; thanks in advance for any and all feedback provided.

I'm building a web scraper using the Playwright Python API. There's an element on a page, related to an authentication flow, that only loads after waiting a significant amount of time. When clicked, it redirects the user several times until the authentication process is complete.

To reduce the waiting time, I thought of executing the JavaScript associated to the element with `page.evaluate()`, since the JS file is shipped as soon as the page is loaded. Like so:

```py
    with page.expect_navigation(wait_until="domcontentloaded", url=targetUrl):
        page.evaluate(r"startAuthFlow('authFlow');")
```

The method works: it always redirects to the desired page. However, around 20% of times, the following error occurs:

`Execution context was destroyed, most likely because of a navigation`

In testing, I've tried adding timeouts before and after the call to `page.evaluate()`, which on the surface seems to reduce the amount of crashes, however, the process is still unstable and adding timeouts beats the purpose of the solution.

I thought the `page.expect_navigation()` context was exactly for that purpose. Is there something I am fundamentally not understanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[expect_navigation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-navigation) : `This method is deprecated as its  inherently racy`, please use [page.wait_for_url()](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-url) instead.

```
page.click("a.delayed-navigation") # clicking the link will indirectly cause a navigation
page.wait_for_url("**/target.html")
```

Source: https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-navigation